# prove that if $|f(z)|\geq |z|+|\sin(z)|$ then it cannot be an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

> **Problem:** Prove that if $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}.|f(z)|\geq |z|+|\sin(z)|$ then it cannot be an entire function.

I thought about claiming that $f$ must be a polynomial because it has a pole in infinity, but I stuck why it polynomial cannot satisfy this property.

Comment: How are you *sure* that this $f$ nhas a pole at infinity? I ask since $\sin(z)$ is not bounded on $\mathbb{C}$ making it unobvious that adding $z$ to it will cause a pole at infinity,

Comment: nope. though I believe it can be shown with a taylor series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $f$ entire:

$|f(z)|\geq |z|+|\sin(z)| \ge |z|$ implies $f(z) \to \infty, z \to \infty$ hence $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n \ge 1$

But then if $f=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kz^k, M=\max |a_k|$ we have that $| f(iR)| \le M(n+1)R^n$ for $R >1$

On the other hand $2|\sin (iR)|=|e^{-R}-e^{R}| \ge e^R-1$ so one gets the inequality:

$e^R-1 \le 2M(n+1)R^n$ for all $R>1$ where $M,n$ are fixed and that is plainly impossible since $e^R/R^n \to \infty, R \to \infty$ so we get a contradiction!

Comment: Just one observation that $f$ can only have zeroes at the origin thus it is of the form $f(z)=cz^k$ for some $c \in \Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$ and $k \ge 1$

Answer (score 2):

Assume $f$ is entire and satisfies the given inequality. Then $|f(z)|\to \infty$ as $|z|\to \infty.$ Yes, you're right: This implies $f$ is a polynomial. (Make sure you know why.)

But notice $|f(iy)| \ge |\sin(iy)|,$ and $ |\sin(iy)|$ grows like $e^y$ as $y\to \infty.$ That is a growth rate no polynomial can match, and we have a contradiction.